# My javaScript code doesn't allow to scroll down on ipad landscape mode, but it is OK on portrait mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wordpress, ipad

I am using WordPress theme, I input the following code into my front-page-template in order to link the shop to my website. Every browser and mobile so far is OK, only when I use iPad landscape mode, it doesn't allow me to scroll down, but if I use portrait mode, everything is fine. Of course, if I remove this code from the template, then no problem, but I need this code to link my website to the shop. I had tried to remove it from the front page, and enqueue it on the `function.php` and `.js` file, no luck. How should I solve this problem, appreciate! My website is www.sayhitoworld.com, you can check it out on the iPad if you had time and had iPad. Appreciate.

```html
<script>
      var spread_shop_config= {
          "shopName" : "sayhitoworld",
          "locale" : "us_US",
          "prefix" : "//shop.spreadshirt.com",
          "baseId" : "myshop"
   };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//shop.spreadshirt.com/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had time and I had an iPad. Your website works fine in my iPad Mini and Safari

Comment: Thanks for your time. Works fine on the ipad landscape mode? Which version of ipad you have? I only test it on ipad2 so far.

Comment: iPad Mini with iOS 8.3 installed, I checked on Safari

Comment: Have you tried [localizing](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) your script?